# nginx and php fpm in dokcer image pointless response on Amazon ECS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have a Laravel project running on the Amazon ECS(with aws load balancer) and It contains php fpm and nginx. It exposes Nginx 80 port. But sometimes It returns pointless responses like this

```
<span style='display:none'>
 d85371f57439c77c184143f74df8359a
</span>
```

I couldn’t find any problem with that on the Internet. I hope anyone can help me

Also, nginx and Amazon don’t write any error logs. I couldn’t find any error log about that

Comment: I've encountered the same issue on a custom docker env with ngnix (nginx/1.21.6) + php-fpm PHP/8.0.19). At this time, I didn't found any other solution that restarting the service...

Comment: currently there is no another way for solution. I do same thing (